# Bounding a distribution using moments

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a non-negative random variable with bounded image. I was wondering if anybody knew of any results that could answer a question of the following type: Suppose the $n$-th moment satisfies $$f(n)\leq \mathbb{E}[X^n]\leq g(n).$$ With appropriate assumptions on $f(n)$, $g(n)$, in what sense can one approximate the distribution of $X$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the moments of $X$ are close to that of another random variable $Y$, it may be possible to show that the distribution of $X$ is also close to $Y$ by taking apart the proof of the Carleman/moment continuity theorem (see e.g. Theorem 4 in the notes https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/). What are some examples of $f$ and $g$ for which you'd like to draw conclusions?